# Magento 1.6.2 - Issue with checkout

Tags: php, javascript, magento, e-commerce

I'm facing a weird issue with Magento 1.6.2 on my dev server. (we're finalizing our tests in order to go live from a 1.6.0 -> 1.6.2 upgrade).

During checkout, there is an issue.

You start the checkout process.
You create a new account.

You check "Livrer à cette adresse" (Ship to this address)

It should skip to Step 4 directly.
It's not... it's doing nothing, then you have to click on Step 3, then
you have to validate again.

I've removed my theme and everything, we're now using default for everything.

I can't seem to figure the Javascript/code issue. And now I really think it's inside the core.

Do you have any idea ? Anyone facing same issues with 1.6.2 ?

WORKING SOLUTION : I had removed the state field in 1.6.0 using a dirty hack found editing core file.
By reinstalling the whole Magento 1.6.2. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

> You put something in the basket (http://dev.maboiteabeaute.com//checkout/cart/add?product=36&qty=1) You start the checkout process. You create a new account.
>
> You check "Livrer à cette adresse" (Ship to this address)

just did that, and got straight to step 4, "Mode de livraison". Both on FF and chrome, in ubuntu.